# Secure typescript model

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor

I'm using angularjs2 + Meteor for development. Problen here is that I've write model in following style -

```
export interface temp {
  name: string;
  count: number;    
}
```

Problem here is that, I'm using typescript for file extention, so after compiling it converted into original text. So this model is not secure. User can able to insert any type of data, This is the main problem.

In meteor + reactJs app, I've used Meteor.collection which is gives security. But here how can we make model more secure in typescript ?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does not provide runtime type checking. You would have to write that yourself.

```
ensureArgIsTemp(arg: temp): arg is temp {
  if (!arg 
      || Object.keys(arg).length !== 2
      || typeof arg.name !== "string" 
      || typeof arg.count !== "number")
    throw new Error("The given object does not match the interface `temp`");

  return true;
}
```

You might be able to automate some of this by using the experimental decorators. See http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4

Comment: @Knagis Do you know about how can we use meteor simple schema with typescript ? Its my question.

Comment: @Shubham then state it explicitly in your question